# ruby won't print output

Tags: ruby, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to see if the user enters a prime number. I want it to print "PRIME" or "NOT PRIME" to screen:

```
prime = ""
puts "TYPE IN A NUMBER TO SEE IF IT'S PRIME: "
gets.chomp(prime).to_i
for divide_by in 2..(prime.to_i - 1)
    if prime % divide_by == 0
        puts "NOT PRIME!!!"
else
    puts "PRIME!!!"
end
end
```

Should I use a `while` loop instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your `gets.chomp(prime).to_i` is not doing anything significant. I don't understand the purpose of `chomp` here, and it is not assigning any variable. If you want to receive the input number as `prime`, you need to do `prime = gets.to_i`.

Once you do that, you do not need to do `to_i` again as in `for divide_by in 2..(prime.to_i - 1)`.

Furthermore, your logic is flawed. If `prime` is not divisible by `2`, is that enough to say `"PRIME!!"`? I don't think so.

And if you are wondering what type of loop to use, the `for` loop is rarely useful. You should use `each`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I then do something with the number? Do I put it in the same loop?

Comment: Put what in the same loop as what?

Comment: "If prime is not divisible by 2, is that enough to say "PRIME!!"?"

I know. I was trying to say by any number between 1 and prime, not counting 1.

I'll try to do it with a for each loop.